# Windows 8 scan profile missing black and white option (Kodak esp 1.2)

Tags: windows-8, scanning, document-scanning

I have recently changed to Windows 8 and have connected our Kodak esp 1.2 printer/scanner using the out of the box Windows driver (previously we had an XP machine and used the Kodak driver bundle). The printer is attached via WiFi and has worked flawlessly for scanning and printing so far. My wife makes line drawings using black gel pen and scans them in to make worksheets - these ideally need to be scanned in black and white as colour and greyscale pick up imperfections etc in the paper. When scanning, there is only the option to scan in colour or greyscale, so I thought no problem, add a black and white scan profile. However when I go to do this (via Control Panel -> Scanners and Cameras -> Scan Profiles -> Add...) the black and white option is missing in the Colour format drop down box - it only contains Colour and Greyscale as options.

*I have tried to include an image here but don't have enough rep!*

I have seen example screenshots on the web of this dialog with a black and white option. Any ideas why this might be missing? Is it specific to the model of printer/scanner?

*I guess I could scan in greyscale and convert to B&W but I'd like to know why this doesn't work and if it can be fixed.*

Comment: No updated Win8 drivers available from Kodak?

Comment: The drivers were updated in October, I tried those initially not realising Win8 could work out of the box, and had all sorts of problems with the printer (attached by WiFi) showing as offline at random moments having just worked and then needing to reboot to pick it up again. It was pingable. I'm wondering if there was an issue of it clashing with the built in drivers?